# Jlist, can't delete all files related

Tags: java, eclipse, jlist

I am trying out a program where I need to delete files inside a main folder, but not delete the folder itself.

The following code does that but I am facing a problem, where only the first folder's files are deleted from the JList which holds in total 3 folders.

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong?

```
class ClearListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object selected = list.getSelectedValue();
        try {
            removeIndexInterval();
            deleteFiles(selected);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    }

    public void removeIndexInterval() {
        DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel) this.list.getModel();
        if (this.list.getSelectedIndices().length > 0) {
            int[] tmp = this.list.getSelectedIndices();
            int[] selectedIndices = this.list.getSelectedIndices();
            for (int i = tmp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                selectedIndices = this.list.getSelectedIndices();
                dlm.removeElementAt(selectedIndices[i]);
            } // end-for
        } // end-i
    }

    public void deleteFiles(Object objects) throws IOException {
        File[] files = ((File) objects).listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                String fileName = file.getName();
                boolean del = file.delete();
                System.out.println(fileName + " : Deleted ? " + del);
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                deleteFiles(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: jlist holds in total 3 folders and only the first folder's files are deleted?

Comment: I have a directory that have 3 folders, if i add more, it will appear more, i just have 3 xD

Comment: Yes if i use the MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION, for select more than one in my list, just the first in the list that is deleted